# Errors when launching/repairing/etc. in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm getting this error when I launch the SQL Management Studio 2016.

[image]

How can I solve this?

I tried to reinstall several times (the installation process does not throw any errors) and when I try to "repair" the installation I got 0x800713ec error.

I also have this error when I open the databases folder.

[image]

Comment: You don't mention the SSMS version. If you have a version that is older than 2017, just install the latest SMSS (it's free and they go side-by-side). It should be able to do everything the old version can do, and more.

Comment: Im using the 2016 version, but I can't install 2017 because there is no installation package to a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Run Windows update
- Run SSMS as administrator
- Make sure you are not using any add-on plugin such as SQL Assistant or the like.
- If you are using version 2012 make sure to install Service Pack 1.
- Install [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)